# Nuclear reaction – What is the asterisk an indication of?

Tags: electrons, radiation, notation, radioactivity

I've been observing the two-step decay of iodine-131 and can't quite determine what the asterisk above Xenon-131 indicates, for instance in the [decay process according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine-131#Radioactive_decay):

[image: decay process of Iodine-131 into Xenon-131, with an asterisk on the Xenon]

I'm currently unsure as to what precisely the superscript asterisk on Xenon is. Apologies for the meekly idiotic inquiry, I'm not all too educated on this matter.

Comment: On a related note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_isomer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the nucleus is not in its ground state but in an excited one. As such, Xe* can and does further decay into the ground state of Xe.

Comment: More precisely, since it is a nuclear reaction, the nucleus is not in the ground state.

Comment: You're much right, I'll correct my answer

Comment: It may be worth noting that occasionally this means the first excited state in particular (with $\mathrm{Xe}^{**}$ meaning the second state and $\mathrm{Xe}^{***}$ the third, etc) but that that the same notation is often used in an inclusive manner to mean *any* excited state. Which meaning is intended must generally be extracted from the context.